# Block specific UDP packets - windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have Windows Server 2012 and some app on it. But someone sending packets (I know which packets, this packets: 0C 19, 0C 20, 0C, 21 etc.). And I want to block it. Is there some way how to do it? I found app "wpe" but it is limited with blocking only 40 packets.